# Accessing database ID in Graphene/Graphql

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I have the following query which filters for a shop with the shown ID (using sqlalchemy):

```
{
  shop(id: "mydevappstore") {
    id
  }
}
```

The produces the following result. I would expect the id be the same as above:

```
{
  "data": {
    "shop": {
      "id": "U2hvcDpteWRldmFwcHN0b3Jl"
    }
  }
}
```

I don't understand why this happens (also in the Graphene tutorial) and how to fix it.

sqlalchemy_and_graphene.py is

```
Base = declarative_base()

class ShopModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'shop'
    id = Column(String(128), primary_key=True)

class Shop(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ShopModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )
```

Comment: How does your database table look like? also, add relevant portions of your code

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I hope I made it more understandable now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the `id` field with the help of ***`source`*** argument

```
import graphene
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType


class Shop(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    any_name = graphene.String(source='id')

    class Meta:
        model = ShopModel
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

Comment: so then the database id field can be accessed by anyName. Is it possible to expose it as ID? Unfortunalty id = graphene.String(source='id') leads to "AssertionError: Node.id expects type "ID!" but Shop.id provides type "String"."

Comment: Could you try to change `graphene.Int(...)` ?

Comment: No, doesn't work. Problem seems to be the relay.Node interface. What works is subclassing relay node like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490229/retrieve-the-

Comment: Yes, I too have seen that. But, my solution will work for Django. I am sure about that.